# Root class is not read by SASS, only those with ampersand are

Tags: css, vue.js, sass

I have a sass/css class with an ampersand, this is used in conjunction with VueJS. What I was wondering is that the CSS attribute assigned on the ampersand is working but the root element itself isn't detected by the browser.

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>
.curved-input {
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-right: 1rem;

  &__lg {
    width: 300px;
  }

  &__sm {
    width: 150px;
  }
}
</style>
```

Here's the explanation, the browser seem to detect the `width: 300px` or `width: 150px` but not the `border-radius, height, margin-right`.

```
<input name="city" class="curved-input__lg" type="text" placeholder="Palau Ujong, Singapore"/>
```

The textbox width changed but other attributes are not read by the browser when you look at them on the browser tools. Am I missing something here?

My goal is not to code it as `class="curved-input curved-input__lg` but rather only use `curved-input__lg` or `curved-input__sm` while inheriting the parent attributes (curved-input).

Comment: Well you can split the classes into `curved-input` ,  `__lg` as two different classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `@extend` to avoid adding additional classes to your markup or (some) duplicate code, if that is your goal.

```
.curved-input {
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

.curved-input {
  &__lg {
    @extend .curved-input;
    width: 300px;
  }

  &__sm {
    @extend .curved-input;
    width: 150px;
  }
}
```

Which would generate the following CSS

```
.curved-input, 
.curved-input__sm, 
.curved-input__lg {
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

.curved-input__lg {
  width: 300px;
}
.curved-input__sm {
  width: 150px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you have to declare the `curved-input` class as well. So your class attribute will look like `class="curved-input curved-input__lg"`.

If you'd write out your CSS in full you'll get something like this:

```
.curved-input {
   border-radius: 5px;
   height: 50px;
   margin-right: 1rem;
}

.curved-input__lg {
   width: 300px;
}

.curved-input__sm {
   width: 150px;
}
```

With this in mind you'll see that you have to add the class `curved-input` as well.

Comment: Yes, exactly it works like that when I set it as `curved-input curved-input__lg` but is there a way to revise this that I'll just set my class as `curved-input__lg` or `curved-input__sm` but it will inherit the `curved-input` class?

Comment: You can by add the border-radius, height and margin to the `__lg` and `__sm` classes. But then you'll be surpassing the use of BEM like you're doing here. So I recommend using `curved-input curved-input__lg` as your class attribute

Answer (score 0):

Well if you want to write it like that, try to change the first line to:

```
[class*="curved-input"]
```